# No route matches [POST] "/collections/1/photos/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can somebody help me with this error?

I just started a basic Rails project where i have **Collections**. Every Collection can have multiple **Photos**.

However, it is possible for me to create those Collections. But whenenver I want to create a Photo attached to a Collection i get this error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/collections/1/photos/new"
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  resources :collections do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

collection_controller.rb

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_collection, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /collections
  # GET /collections.json
  def index
    @collections = Collection.all
  end

  # GET /collections/1
  # GET /collections/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /collections/new
  def new
    @collection = Collection.new
  end

  # GET /collections/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /collections
  # POST /collections.json
  def create
    @collection = Collection.new(collection_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @collection.save
        format.html { redirect_to @collection, notice: 'Collection was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @collection }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @collection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /collections/1
  # PATCH/PUT /collections/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @collection.update(collection_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @collection, notice: 'Collection was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @collection }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @collection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /collections/1
  # DELETE /collections/1.json
  def destroy
    @collection.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to collections_url, notice: 'Collection was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_collection
      @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def collection_params
      params.require(:collection).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

photos_controller.rb

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /photos
  # GET /photos.json
  def index
    @photos = Photo.all
  end

  # GET /photos/1
  # GET /photos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /photos/new
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  # GET /photos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /photos
  # POST /photos.json
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        redirect_to @photo
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /photos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /photos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update(photo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /photos/1
  # DELETE /photos/1.json
  def destroy
    @photo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to photos_url, notice: 'Photo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_photo
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:name, :collection_id)
    end
end
```

photos/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Photo</h1>

<%= render 'form', photo: @photo %>

<%= link_to 'Back', collection_photos_path %>
```

photos/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@collection, @photo], url: new_collection_photo_path do |f| %>
  <% if photo.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(photo.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this photo from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% photo.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>Naam:</p>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is having wrong URL

`new_collection_photo_path`

It should be

`collection_photos_path`

Comment: It fixed the error. But for some reason I then get the following error in my photos_controller:  

undefined method `photo_url' for #<PhotosController:0x007fb8d0eb6de8> Did you mean? photo_params  


Extracted source (around line #31):             
    respond_to do |format|  
      if @photo.save  
        redirect_to @photo  
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }  
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @photo }  
      else

Comment: @royketelaar Sorry unable to understand in this format can you make new question as this is new bug

Comment: Yeah it's kinda hard to format a comment, i'll make a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809196/undefined-method-error-on-a-nested-resource-index-page